# Is there a way to name an object with a portion of the name assigned elsewhere? Rstudio

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I'm a relatively inexperienced coder using R to try and clean some data. In doing so, I'm trying to write code that will do the same thing to several spreadsheets and create outputs with names that match their respective spreadsheet. I want part of each object name to be assigned so I can copy and paste the code for each separate year of data and only have to alter one line of code. What I'm thinking is I could do something similar to this (I know this doesn't work, I just don't know if something similar or better is possible). Thanks!

```
XX<- 05 #the last two digits of the year data is gathered
sheetXX <- read_excel("file path for data2005")
sheetXX.1 <- rbind(sheetXX, c(as.character("Example row"), 10, 12))
```

The hope is that for all of the commands I use, I'll end up with final products named sheet01.1, sheet02.1, etc. for the years 2001 and 2002, for example.

Comment: Hi broodoots, welcome to SO! I'm not quite sure what you're looking for exactly, or how your current code doesn't do what you need... but the functions `get()` and `paste()` might help you do some of this programmatically. For example, if everywhere you need a year you use a variable like XX, you can go through all the years with a `for` loop, an `apply()` family function, or something like `map()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over a vector of file names to read them into R like this:

```
xl_sheets <- lapply(dir(pattern = "xlsx"), read_excel)
```

This creates a list of all XLSX filenames in the working directory with `dir()` then feeds those one by one into `readxl::read_excel()`. The result is a list of dataframes that correspond with the XLSX files in your working directory.

To give them names that correspond to the file names you could do:

```
names(xl_sheets) <- dir(pattern = "xlsx")
```

To manipulate all dataframes at the same time, you could use `lapply()` again:

```
lapply(xl_sheets, function(x) add_column(x, a = 1))
```

If you want to execute different operations on each dataframe you can access each one with

```
xl_sheets[[1]]
xl_sheets[[2]]
...
```

or

```
xl_sheets$file_name_a
xl_sheets$file_name_b
...
```

Or you can use `list2env()` to obtain each dataframe as a single object in your environment.

```
list2env(xl_sheets, xl_sheets, envir = globalenv())
```